# Chaining Tasks with Different Return Types

Tags: c#, .net, .net-4.0, task-parallel-library

Is it possible to chain tasks with different return types or no return type at all? For example in pseudo-code:

```cs
Task<double>.ContinueWith(Task<string>).ContinueWith(Task<String>).ContinueWith(Task)
```

Or also here is real-code example:

```cs
private double SumRootN(int root)
{
    double result = 0;
    for (int i = 1; i < 10000000; i++)
    {
        result += Math.Exp(Math.Log(i) / root);
    }
    return result;
}

private void taskSequentialContinuationButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Task<double> task = null;

    this.statusText.Text = "";
    this.watch = Stopwatch.StartNew();
    for (int i = 2; i < 20; i++)
    {
        int j = i;
        if (task == null)
        {
            task = Task<double>.Factory.StartNew(() => { return SumRootN(j); });
        }
        else
        {
            task = task.ContinueWith((t) => { return SumRootN(j); });
        }

        task = task.ContinueWith((t) => 
        { // I don't want to return anything from this task but I have to, to get it to compile
            this.statusText.Text += String.Format("root {0} : {1}\n", j, t.Result);
            return t.Result;
        }, TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext());
    }

    task.ContinueWith((t) => 
        { // I also don't want to return anything here but I don't seem to have to here even though intellisense expects a Task<double>??
            this.statusText.Text += String.Format("{0}ms elapsed\n", watch.ElapsedMilliseconds);
        }, TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext());
}
```

See the inline comments for the oddities of the chaining.

Comment: Why exactly do you have so many `Task`s in sequence? Can't you run the loop in a single `Task`, that creates the `SynchronizationContext` `Task`s?

Comment: That would indeed be a better solution but how do you get the UI thread context in that single task on a different thread?  I know this can be done with a Dispatcher but that makes the code dependent on the UI framework.  Is it possible to pass in a reference to the UI thread?  Can you make a code example?

Comment: I think the code sample here might do more harm than good.  Can you explain what you're looking for in terms of runtime behavior?  The code as-is appears to 'throw away' the results of all but the last SumRootN call since your ContinueWith calls don't use the 't' or 't.Result'

Comment: FWIW, based on what I think you're trying to do, you might also consider Parallel.For - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.parallel.for.aspx

Comment: It is just example throw away code. It will not be used in an application.  I'm trying to create a *sequentially* executed chain of tasks that updates the UI with continuation tasks running in the UI thread.  Tasks which update the UI don't need to pass a value to the next task but the code will not compile unless they do.  Hence the title "Chaining Tasks with Different Return Types" - is it possible?

Comment: @JamesManning The computation here is not parallel at all. I'm not sure making it parallel is what's wanted, especially since it would mean the results will be in wrong order.

Comment: @svick - perhaps it shouldn't be, but you can see that 't' isn't used in this code, right?   task.ContinueWith((t) => { return SumRootN(j); });

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to chain `Task`s with different return types, you can just put each of them in a different variable:

```
Task<Type1> task1 = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => Compute1());
Task<Type2> task2 = task1.ContinueWith(_ => Compute2());
Task<Type3> task3 = task2.ContinueWith(_ => Compute3());
```

For your specific case, where you compute something in a loop and want to report on the UI thread after each iteration, you can do it like this:

```
var uiScheduler = TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext();

Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
{
    for (int i = 2; i < 20; i++)
    {
        // perform computation

        Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
        {
            // report result
        }, CancellationToken.None, TaskCreationOptions.None, uiScheduler);
    }
});
```

Comment: FWIW, if you want to report progress in a loop, it'd likely be simpler to just use BackgroundWorker.

Comment: @JamesManning If that's really all you want to do, then yeah. But using `Task`s means that if you want to change anything, it will most likely be much easier.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is complicated by your re-use of a single `task` variable. It looks like you want to launch a number of tasks and wait for them to complete. Something like this should work:

```
SynchronizationContext context = SynchronizationContext.Current;

Task[] tasks = Enumerable.Range(2, 19)
    .Select(d => Task<double>.Factory.StartNew(() => SumRootN(d))
        .ContinueWith(t => {
            this.statusText.Text += string.Format("root {0} : {1}\n", d, t.Result);
        }))
    .ToArray();

Task.Factory.StartNew(() => {
    Task.WaitForAll(tasks);
    string msg = string.Format("{0}ms elapsed\n", watch.ElapsedMilliseconds);
    context.Post(_ => { this.statusText.Text += msg; }, null);
});
```

EDIT: If you want to create a chain of tasks, this might work:

```
Task first = new Task(() => { });
Task outer = Enumerable.Range(2, 19)
    .Aggregate(first, (task, d) => {
        Task inner = new Task<double>(() => SumRootN(d))
            .ContinueWith(rt => {
                this.statusText.Text += String.Format("root {0} : {1}\n", d, rt.Result);
            });
        return task.ContinueWith(inner);
    });

outer.ContinueWith(t => {
    this.statusText.Text += String.Format("{0}ms elapsed\n", watch.ElapsedMilliseconds);
});

first.Start();
```

Comment: This will freeze the UI while the code is executing. You really shouldn't `Wait()` (or `WaitForAll()`) on the `SynchronizationContext`.

Comment: That code is simpler for sure, but I'm trying to chain the tasks together so they execute *sequentially* in the background. What I mean is do SumRootN(2) -> display result in UI -> SumRootN(3) -> display result in UI -> ... -> display total time.

I know it is much faster to do them in parallel but I'm actually just trying to make an example of how you would wire up a sequential chain (possibly with each "link" in the chain having a different return type).

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx

Comment: Specifically, since you have a single serial task and you just want to report progress and when you're done, your code will be much simpler just using a single BackgroundWorker instance (which automatically deals with having your ShowProgress and completed methods called on the UI thread) rather than Tasks